# Categories and Subcategories showing products for the parent and children

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Im doing a ecommerce website with django and I have a problem with categories and subcategories. This are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
title = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null = True) 
ordering = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name = 'variants', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='products', null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
price = models.FloatField(null = True)
disccount = models.BooleanField(default = False)
disccount_price = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
```

And this is my view:

```
def category_detail(request, slug):
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
products = category.products.filter(parent = None)
context = {
    'category': category,
    'products' : products
}

return render(request, 'category_detail.html', context)
```

Okay so what I want to do is if I click the parent category I want to show all the products that their children have and If I click a Children I want to show only the products that he has. So i don't know how to do that:(